# Log start/end times of user input/activity on MacOS

Tags: macos, logs

I'd like to keep a log of when I start and end a session sitting at my Macbook. Let's say a session starts when the displays are black and I use the keyboard/mouse to wake the Macbook (and enter my password), and ends when the displays black out again due to inactivity.

In order of preference, I'd like to:

- get this from an existing log, going back a year or so;
- turn on something built-in to log this information going forward;
- use some third party tool which can do it. In that case, suggestions would be welcome.

My purpose is basically the same as [Get Historic System Event Logs (Sleep, Restart, Wake-up etc)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437656/get-historic-system-event-logs-sleep-restart-wake-up-etc), but the answers there didn't help. I don't explicitly log out or put my Mac to sleep, so perhaps the events I'm after are different.